# How to validate uploaded image is of height 65px

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In my controller i am using function to upload site logo but i want to validate that the logo image is of height 65px How can i implement this in cakephp.
thanks

```
   if ($this->request->is('post')||$this->request->is('put')) {

        if (!empty($this->data['GlobalAdminSetting']['site_logo']['name']) && is_uploaded_file($this->data['GlobalAdminSetting']['site_logo']['tmp_name'])) {
            $allowedType = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png');
            if (!is_dir(APP . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'siteImg/')) {
                mkdir(APP . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'siteImg/');
                chmod(APP . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'siteImg/', 0777);
            }

            $imageName = $this->data['GlobalAdminSetting']['site_logo'];
            unset($this->request->data['GlobalAdminSetting']['site_logo']);
            if (!in_array($imageName['type'], $allowedType)) {
                $this->request->data['GlobalAdminSetting']['site_logo'] = 'invalidFormat';
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry, Logo could not be uploaded. only jpeg,png are allowed.'));

            } else {
                if ($imageName != '') {
                    $filePath = APP . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'siteImg/' . $imageName['name'];
                    move_uploaded_file($imageName['tmp_name'], $filePath);
                    chmod(APP . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'siteImg/'. $imageName['name'], 0777);
                    $this->GlobalAdminSetting->save(array('id' => 1, 'site_logo' => 'siteImg/'. $imageName['name']));
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('site logo is uploaded Successfully.'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image Not Found to upload.'));
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image Not Found to upload.'));
        }
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'global_admin_settings', 'action' => 'logo'));
    } else{
   $this->set('logo',$this->GlobalAdminSetting->findById(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). That function takes a path to an image as input and returns an array of image data. The first to array keys contain width and height respectively.

I'm not sure when you want to validate the height (before or after file upload), but if you want the validation to be part of the Model's validation rules you may write a custom validation function [as documented here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules). The first variable of a validation rule function contains the relevant form data (named `$check` in the documentation) which you can then use in combination with `getimagesize()`.